# javax.servlet.ServletException deployin portlet

Tags: deployment, jboss7.x, liferay-6, web-deployment, spring-portlet-mvc

I have a Liferay SpringMVC Portlet that deploy successfully but I have to put this portlet inside other portlet that contains another 32 components.
Inside this component, my portlet is not been deployed trowing the following error:

```
12:36:11,780 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/ibermutua-portlet].[view-servlet]] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-4) JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for servlet view-servlet threw exception: javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not complete render request: View is null
12:36:11,791 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-4) 12:36:11,791 ERROR [http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-4][render_portlet_jsp:132] null

12:36:11,791 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-4) javax.portlet.PortletException

12:36:11,791 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-4)   at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:614)

12:36:11,791 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-4)   at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeRender(InvokerPortletImpl.java:677)

12:36:11,791 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-4)   at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.render(InvokerPortletImpl.java:379)

12:36:11,791 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-4)   at org.apache.jsp.html.portal.render_005fportlet_jsp._jspService(render_005fportlet_jsp.java:1201)

12:36:11,791 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-4)   at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:69)

12:36:11,791 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-4)   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)

12:36:11,792 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-4)   at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:365)

12:36:11,792 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-4)   at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:309)

12:36:11,792 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-4)   at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:242)

12:36:11,792 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-4)   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)

12:36:11,792 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-4)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295)

12:36:11,792 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-4)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)

12:36:11,792 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-4)   at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)

12:36:11,792 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-4)   at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:96)

12:36:11,792 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-4)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)

12:36:11,792 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-4)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)

12:36:11,792 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-4)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:832)

12:36:11,792 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-4)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:718)

12:36:11,792 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-4)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:655)

12:36:11,792 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-4)   at com.liferay.portal.servlet.DirectServletPathRegisterDispatcher.include(DirectServletPathRegisterDispatcher.java:55)
```

My liferay-portlet.xml.

```
<portlet>
        <portlet-name>33</portlet-name>
        <icon>/icon.png</icon>
        <instanceable>true</instanceable>       
        <private-session-attributes>false</private-session-attributes>
        <header-portlet-css>/css/main.css</header-portlet-css>
        <header-portlet-javascript>/js/jquery-1.12.1.min.js</header-portlet-javascript>
        <footer-portlet-javascript>/js/main.js</footer-portlet-javascript>
    </portlet>
```

My web.xml

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>view-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewRendererServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>view-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/33/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

My portlet.xml

```
<portlet>
        <portlet-name>33</portlet-name>
        <display-name>AgregadoresContenidos</display-name>
        <portlet-class>org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet</portlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <name>view-template</name>
            <value>/portlets/33-agregadores-contenidos/confInicial.jsp</value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <name>contextConfigLocation</name>
            <value>/WEB-INF/contexts/AgregadoresContenidos-portlet.xml</value>
        </init-param>       
        <supports>
            <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
            <portlet-mode>view</portlet-mode>
            <portlet-mode>edit</portlet-mode>
        </supports>
        <resource-bundle>content.Language</resource-bundle>
        <portlet-info>
            <title>AgregadoresContenidos</title>
            <short-title>AgregadoresContenidos</short-title>
            <keywords>AgregadoresContenidos</keywords>
        </portlet-info>
        <security-role-ref>
            <role-name>administrator</role-name>
        </security-role-ref>
        <security-role-ref>
            <role-name>guest</role-name>
        </security-role-ref>
        <security-role-ref>
            <role-name>power-user</role-name>
        </security-role-ref>
        <security-role-ref>
            <role-name>user</role-name>
        </security-role-ref>
    </portlet>
```

KInd regards,

Comment: it seems that it's not finding the jsp the view is null. are you sure that the path is correct typed.

Comment: Which paths are you meaning? The paths describes on those files are correct, but im not sure if i missing a configuration in any other file.

Comment: Its compatible SpringMVC Portlet with MVC Portlet in the same Liferay plugin Project?
Because if not, I've just found the problem.

Comment: i mean the path of the jsp. but i think the problem is you have to mapping the  `org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewRendererServlet ` this way
 `<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ViewRendererServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/servlet/view</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>`

Comment: If I put this <url-pattern> i receive an error to, error saying that "The requested resource (/ibermutua-portlet/33/invoke) is not available"
I've checked the path and its correct